# How to style 4 grids in a page when my pages have more than 4 grids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My pages have 6 grids called grid1,grid2,grid3,grid4,grid5,grid6.When I click the search button,I read the data in grids.now I want to style the grid1,grid2,grid4,grid5 with style `"color:red"`,I can style them using these codes:

```
   #grid1.k-grid-content td {
   color:red 
   } 
   #grid2.k-grid-content td {
   color:red 
   } 
   #grid4.k-grid-content td {
   color:red 
   } 
   #grid5.k-grid-content td {
   color:red 
   }
```

I think this way is really  complicated and redundant and change the codes like this and click the search button,but failed.But if I firstly seach data,and then execute the change code,it successed.How to change my code?I just do not want to write complicated and redundant codes.Can it be used with jquery "live" event?Anybody use "live" to style the grid td?

```
   .GridColor {
   color:red 
   } 
     $(function () {
    $("#grid1.k-grid-content  td").addClass("GridColor");
    $("#grid2.k-grid-content  td").addClass("GridColor");
    $("#grid4.k-grid-content  td").addClass("GridColor");
    $("#grid5.k-grid-content  td").addClass("GridColor");
     }
```

Comment: create a fiddle please.

Comment: note that 'live' is deprecated and should be replaced with the 'on' event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('Search').on("click",function(){
$("#grid1.k-grid-content  td").addClass("GridColor");
    $("#grid2.k-grid-content  td").addClass("GridColor");
    $("#grid4.k-grid-content  td").addClass("GridColor");
    $("#grid5.k-grid-content  td").addClass("GridColor");
});



 .GridColor {
   color:red !important;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks,I found that my changes codes failed because at first I have not clicked the "Search" button and the grid do not have any data(the grid have not any "td" to color red).Can you use "live" binding to style the td.I think "live" binding may be useful.

Comment: If you use `live` make sure you you 1.7.1.js or greater version because after 1.7.1 `live` function is remove.

Comment: Do you think that use css style is more efficient than use javascript in my question?Or just they are the same efficient.

Comment: Both same.....if it's help full then accept ans so any body have same problem then he got his ans.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () {
   $("#mybutton").on('click',function(){
 $("[id^='grid']").find('td').addClass("GridColor");
 });
 });
```

this finds all elements with an ID beginning with grid, then targets all td's adn adds the class

Comment: Thanks,I found that my changes codes failed because at first I have not clicked the "Search" button and the grid do not have any data(the grid have not any "td" to color red).Can you use "live" binding to style the td.I think "live" binding may be useful.

Comment: .live was deprecated after jQuery version 1.7, .on is it's replacement. If you are using jQuery 1.7 or below, simply replace .on with .live in my example

Comment: Do you think that use css style is more efficient than use javascript in my question?Or just they are the same efficient.